# Making MiniMagick routine run as far as possible on Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick

The following code simply writes a given string to an existing image stored to the file system. It isn't very complex as far as image manipulation goes. However, there is obviously some overhead incurred by invoking MiniMagick. In addition, this routine will be called very frequently, so it needs to complete as quickly as possible.

Other than caching the image to disk, what are my options with rails/ruby to make sure that this code is running at peak performance?

```
variable = "some string"

mm = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/b.png")
  mm.combine_options do |c| 
    c.gravity 'center' 
    c.pointsize '13' 
    c.draw "text 33,0 '#{variable}'" 
  end

 send_data(mm.to_blob, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the HTTP call from the client return as fast as possible? OR are you trying to have this routine run as fas as possible?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Good question. Actually both, but the focus here was on the image processing. But whatever could be tweaked at the protocol level would of course be of great benefit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach for image processing it to do it in the background -- user uploads image (possibly to S3 directly), and then the server processes the image thumbnails in the background.

This keeps the app as fast as possible. This is a way to process carrier wave uploads in the background using resque: https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder

You would then move this image processing to carrier wave as a step, and you're good to go!

Comment: Unfortunately, this process has to stay within the Request/Response cycle since the result has to be displayed immediately. That's why I'm asking this question. Anything that can be done perf. wise assuming that the routine cannot be offloaded with Resque?